# Caching of ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've started recently playing with ReactJS. After doing some reading, few tutorials and checking some existing websites using ReactJS.

What I'm finding a bit mysterious is how for example AirBnB is making their rooms pages being generated despite JavaScript turned off in browser settings.

I did simple experiment (everything done on Chrome):

1. Find any random room on main page and copy it's URL
2. Turn off JS in settings
3. In Incognito window (just to be sure cach and history is clean) open copied URL

My assumption was that nothing will render, but surprisingly - some basic information (including cover picture) has been rendered.

This means some pre-rendered HTML has to be somewhere. And also (although not so certain) it is not single page application just using React Router.

Could someone explain what technology might be hiding behind?

Comment: You can do serverside react rendering.

Comment: If the duplicate does not answer the question in your eyes ping me, I'm open to reopen.